# Double %% in where clause?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a where clause like the below example:

```
WHERE (subject LIKE 'chef%') AND (dep LIKE 'psy%%')
```

What is the difference using 1 or 2 percent signs? I know what one means (wild card), but not what the second adds in functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usage of double '%' is mostly for specifying there are no wildcards present between them.however it is also used for using actual '%' in searchquery which is called escaping.

using '%' escaping looks like

```
SELECT name FROM emp 
   WHERE id LIKE '%\%%' ESCAPE '\'
```

for more details on escaping [Escaping](http://www.orafaq.com/faq/how_does_one_escape_special_characters_when_writing_sql_queries)

Answer (score 6):

That query is likely a typo; putting a double % does nothing in the example you have given as there are no non-wildcard characters between the two %'s.

If you wanted to search for an actual % character you can use [escaping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx).