# Significance of double percent signs (%%) in T-SQL PATINDEX

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I ran across a legacy piece of T-SQL that uses a PATINDEX similar to the following to extract a date out of a text column:

```
CAST(SUBSTRING(MyText, PATINDEX('%%-[0-1][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]%%', DocumentHeaderText)+1, 8) AS DATE)
```

I can't see the reason for the double percent signs at the beginning and end of the wildcard string, and from Googling around and looking at the [PATINDEX documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) it doesn't seem like a double percent sign does anything more than a single percent sign.

However, I've been bitten before by hastily "improving" legacy code, finding out the hard way that the original author had a good reason for what they did and having to change it back.

So my question is, is there any difference between `%%` and `%` in a wildcard string for a T-SQL LIKE or PATINDEX statement? Can I safely change the code without altering the behavior to:

```
CAST(SUBSTRING(MyText, PATINDEX('%-[0-1][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]%', DocumentHeaderText)+1, 8) AS DATE)
```

Comment: This could be similar behavior to what was explained here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/29891436/1316856

Comment: @ParrishHusband I seriously doubt it since the `patindex` function does not have an `escape` parameter. also, there is nothing in the OP's code to suggest an escape char exist between both wildcards.

Comment: @ZoharPeled yes I agree on that last part.  However as we all experience too often, legacy code doesn't always make sense.

Comment: @ParrishHusband could be just a quick fix (like if at some point it was `%_[0-1]...[0-9]_%` [that actually make sense] and the developer decided they don't actually need at least one char before and after, but instead of deleting the `_` the just converted it into `%` by mistake).

Comment: @ZoharPeled yeah good thinking

Comment: Having %%-s can have other reason. If you use sql-s e.g. in Python and you call cursor.execute(sql) and you have things like %s -s in it, then you need to have the percent signs doubled. Like cursor.execute("SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE id <> %s AND data LIKE '%%hello world%%'", [50]) . See https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [official documentation of `PATINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) states that:

> *pattern*
>   Is a character expression that contains the sequence to be found. Wildcard characters can be used; however, the `%` character must come before and follow pattern (except when you search for first or last characters)

The `%` wildcard stands for,
as written in the [official documentation for `LIKE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments):

> any string of zero or more characters.

The fact that it can stand for any number of characters including zero, means that `%%` is completely equivalent to `%` and there for can be safely be changed.

Please note that this is not the case with any other T-SQL wildcards - since `_` stands for a single char, as well as `[]` and `[^]`.